# Storybook cannot pass register prop into stories

Tags: reactjs, storybook, react-hook-form, react-forms

I have the following components

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function FormField({
  type,
  name,
  label,
  register,
  required,
  placeholder,
  validationSchema
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
          {label}
          <span className="text-red-500 font-bold text-lg">{required && '*'}</span>
        </label>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <input
            {...register(name, validationSchema)}
            type={type}
            name={name}
            id={name}
            className={['field', `field--${type}`].join(' ')}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

FormField.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(['text', 'email', 'password', 'file', 'checkbox']),
  register: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string
};

FormField.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'text',
  label: 'Label',
  placeholder: ''
};
```

and the following stories file

```
import FormField from './FormField';

export default {
  title: 'Forms/FormField',
  component: FormField,
  argTypes: {
    type: {
      options: ['text', 'email', 'password', 'file', 'checkbox'],
      control: {
        type: 'select'
      }
    }
  }
};

const Template = (args) => <FormField {...args} />;

export const Text = Template.bind({});
Text.args = {
  type: 'text',
  label: 'Text Field',
  name: 'text-field',
  errorMsg: 'Text field is required',
  placeholder: 'Text goes here'
};
```

However, the message I am getting is the following:

```
TypeError: register is not a function
```

How do I pass register into stories even if I'm not using it for my stories?

I've tried passing in and using FormProvider and wrapping the template but that didn't seem to work unless I'm missing something

...

**edit 3**

After chats with Joris I now have the following component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const FormField = React.forwardRef(
  ({ type, name, label, required, placeholder, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
          {label}
          <span className="text-red-500 font-bold text-lg">{required && '*'}</span>
        </label>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <input
            {...props}
            name={name}
            ref={ref}
            type={type}
            id={name}
            className={['field', `field--${type}`].join(' ')}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default FormField;

FormField.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(['text', 'email', 'password', 'file', 'checkbox']),
  register: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string
};

FormField.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'text',
  label: 'Label',
  placeholder: ''
};
```

and now the following page

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Background from '../../../public/images/option1.png';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/client';
import { useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';

// components
import ErrorsPopup from '../../components/ErrorsPopup';
import FormField from '../../components/Forms/FormField';
import Button from '../../components/Button';

export default function Login() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const { handleSubmit, register } = methods;

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      data
    });

    Router.push('/dashboard');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Ellis Development - Login</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="relative">
        <div className="md:flex">
          {/* Image */}
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-700 h-screen lg:w-96">
            <Image src={Background} width={350} height={350} layout="fixed" />
          </div>

          {/* Contact form */}
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center px-6 sm:px-10 w-full">
            <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-grey-800">Login</h1>

            {/* errors */}
            <FormProvider {...methods}>
              <ErrorsPopup />
            </FormProvider>

            <form
              onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="mt-6 flex flex-col gap-y-6 sm:gap-x-8">
              {/* email field */}
              <FormField
                {...register('email', {
                  required: 'Email is required',
                  pattern: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i
                })}
                type="email"
                label="Email"
                placeholder="john.doe@ebrookes.dev"
                required
              />

              {/* password field */}
              <FormField
                {...register('password', {
                  required: 'Password is required'
                })}
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                placeholder="*******"
                required
              />

              <div className="flex items-center justify-between sm:col-span-2">
                <div>
                  <Button type="submit" label="Login" icon="SaveIcon" />
                </div>

                <div>
                  <Link href="/dashboard/auth/register">
                    <a className="underline decoration-blue-500 decoration-4 hover:decoration-2 mr-4">
                      Register
                    </a>
                  </Link>

                  <Link href="/dashboard/auth/forgot">
                    <a className="underline decoration-blue-500 decoration-4 hover:decoration-2">
                      Forgot your password?
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue here now is that the form is still not submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working I now have the following component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const FormField = React.forwardRef(
  ({ type, name, label, required, placeholder, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
          {label}
          <span className="text-red-500 font-bold text-lg">{required && '*'}</span>
        </label>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <input
            {...props}
            name={name}
            ref={ref}
            type={type}
            id={name}
            className={['field', `field--${type}`].join(' ')}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default FormField;

FormField.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(['text', 'email', 'password', 'file', 'checkbox']),
  register: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string
};

FormField.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'text',
  label: 'Label',
  placeholder: ''
};
```

stories

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import FormField from './FormField';

export default {
  title: 'Forms/FormField',
  component: FormField,
  argTypes: {
    type: {
      options: ['text', 'email', 'password', 'file', 'checkbox'],
      control: {
        type: 'select'
      }
    }
  }
};

const Template = (args) => {
  const { register } = useForm();

  return <FormField {...args} register={register} />;
};

export const Text = Template.bind({});
Text.args = {
  type: 'text',
  label: 'Text Field',
  name: 'text-field',
  errorMsg: 'Text field is required',
  placeholder: 'Text goes here'
};

export const Email = Template.bind({});
Email.args = {
  type: 'email',
  name: 'email',
  label: 'Email',
  placeholder: 'john.doe@email.com'
};

export const Password = Template.bind({});
Password.args = {
  type: 'password',
  name: 'password',
  label: 'Password',
  placeholder: '********'
};

export const File = Template.bind({});
File.args = {
  type: 'file',
  name: 'file-upload',
  label: 'File upload'
};

export const Checkboxes = Template.bind({});
Checkboxes.args = {
  type: 'checkbox',
  name: 'check-1',
  label: 'Checkboxes'
};
```

and page

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Background from '../../../public/images/option1.png';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/client';
import { useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';

// components
import ErrorsPopup from '../../components/ErrorsPopup';
import FormField from '../../components/Forms/FormField';
import Button from '../../components/Button';

export default function Login() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const { handleSubmit, register } = methods;

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password
    });

    Router.push('/dashboard');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Ellis Development - Login</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="relative">
        <div className="md:flex">
          {/* Image */}
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-700 h-screen lg:w-96">
            <Image src={Background} width={350} height={350} layout="fixed" />
          </div>

          {/* Contact form */}
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center px-6 sm:px-10 w-full">
            <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-grey-800">Login</h1>

            {/* errors */}
            <FormProvider {...methods}>
              <ErrorsPopup />
            </FormProvider>

            <form
              onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="mt-6 flex flex-col gap-y-6 sm:gap-x-8">
              {/* email field */}
              <FormField
                {...register('email', {
                  required: 'Email is required',
                  pattern: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i
                })}
                type="email"
                name="email"
                label="Email"
                placeholder="john.doe@ebrookes.dev"
                required
              />

              {/* password field */}
              <FormField
                {...register('password', {
                  required: 'Password is required'
                })}
                type="password"
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                placeholder="*******"
                required
              />

              <div className="flex items-center justify-between sm:col-span-2">
                <div>
                  <Button type="submit" label="Login" icon="SaveIcon" />
                </div>

                <div>
                  <Link href="/dashboard/auth/register">
                    <a className="underline decoration-blue-500 decoration-4 hover:decoration-2 mr-4">
                      Register
                    </a>
                  </Link>

                  <Link href="/dashboard/auth/forgot">
                    <a className="underline decoration-blue-500 decoration-4 hover:decoration-2">
                      Forgot your password?
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use hooks in storybook templates like that, many thanks, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve your needs.

```
const Template = (args) => {
  const { register } = useForm();

  return (
    <form>
      <FormField {...args} register={register} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

At react-hook-form, we recommend to forward `ref` instead of passing down the `register` method.

```
const FormField = React.forwardRef(({
  type,
  label,
  required,
  placeholder,
  validationSchema,
  ...props
}, ref) => {
  return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
          {label}
          <span className="text-red-500 font-bold text-lg">{required && '*'}</span>
        </label>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <input
            {...props}
            ref={ref}
            type={type}
            id={name}
            name={name}
            className={['field', `field--${type}`].join(' ')}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
  );
});

export default FormField;
```

And use it a the following:

```
function MyForm() {
  const { register } = useForm();

  return (
    <form>
     <FormField {...register('field-name') />
    </form>
  )
}
```

**Edited: full working example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-mahavira-pfkqs

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

interface Props extends React.PropsWithRef<JSX.IntrinsicElements["input"]> {
  label: string;
}

const FormField = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  ({ label, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label
          htmlFor={props.name}
          className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
        >
          {label}
          <span className="text-red-500 font-bold text-lg">
            {props.required && "*"}
          </span>
        </label>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <input {...props} ref={ref} id={props.name} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

FormField.displayName = "FormField";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();
  console.log(errors);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <FormField
        required
        {...register("myField", { required: "Field is required" })}
        label="Field example"
      />

      <pre>{errors.myField?.message}</pre>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where do you put the MyForm function? Or is that just a page example?

Comment: I've added a page example at the bottom, so wondering how to use your changes within a page

Comment: `MyForm` function is just a page example

Comment: `FormProvider` is required only if you use `useFormContext`. https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext

Comment: i've added another edit

Comment: Can you be more precise please? or provide a codesandbox. There is too much code to understand what you want to attempt to do

Comment: My plan here is to create a FormField component, as mentioned above, I can pass the errors, however, I cannot submit the form. That's my issue, I would like to be able to pass register into the component but I'm just trying to get the form working at the moment with the component fields.

Comment: I've added a full form example. Please have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240285/discussion-between-debugabug-and-joris).

Comment: OK let me cleanup the question

Comment: I've added a #3 error and removed the reset to clean the question